# Read config from executed bin

Tags: go, bin

Im using go viper to read `config` file in my repo

```
myrepo
 -config.yaml
 -main.go
```

I use the following code

```
viper.SetConfigName("config")
viper.AddConfigPath(".")
viper.SetConfigType("yaml")
err := viper.ReadInConfig()
```

And now I compile it to binary and now im running it from 
diffrent path (run the bin) and I got error that the config not found, what could be wrong here ?

The file is there and If I use `ioutil.ReadFile` in debug I get it but not from the executable...

Comment: You deliberately told viper to look in the current working directory only. If the config.yaml is not there it cannot be read. You need to get your logic straight.

Comment: @Volker - what do you mean ? in case I create some go project(which not cli) and put the config as I did in the question it work, the issue is that the binary is not able to access to the yaml file which is part of the binary, this is a bit more complicated then it looks

Comment: Why do you think the yaml file is part of the binary? It is not. Your compiled binary is your binary and the config.yaml is totally unrelated to that binary.

Comment: please dont hard code things , and pass it a path instead of current direcotory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you told viper that it can read the config from the location `./config.yaml`. When you compile the project, the compiler does not compile the configuration data inside `config.yaml` with the binary. Hence, every time the binary runs, it looks for a file `./config.yaml`.

So you have few options here. Either you move the config file with the binary and make sure when you copy the binary, you copy the config as well. Another option you have is to have a flag "configpath" that you pass the config path to and viper should read that flag and fetch the configs. Another option is to put the config inside your .go file and that way the config is compiled (but I am guessing this is something you don't want)